# Need help figuring out how to calculate distinct dates between overlapping date ranges in Access

Tags: date, ms-access

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the distinct number of days that XA was engaged from start to end. Activity started from `7/1/2017` and lasted till `12/26/2017`, but XA was not occupied during all the weekdays from `7/1/2017` till `12/26/2017`. I need to find a way to calculate the number of weekdays that XA was actually occupied.

```
Function    ID    Start         End          Duration

XA          1     10/26/2017    12/2/2017    27
XA          1     10/28/2017    11/26/2017   20
XA          1     10/5/2017     12/26/2017   59
XA          1     7/1/2017      7/17/2017    11
```

Comment: Is the expected answer for your sample data 100 days? 2017-07-01 to 2017-07-17 is 17 days (inclusive) and 2017-10-05 to 2017-12-26 is 83 days (inclusive) and the other two date ranges are already covered in the 83 days? What is the relevance of the `Duration` column if any?

Comment: Oh and I just realised I glossed over the fact that you said **weekdays**. Doh! So the answer certainly isn't 100 liked I suggested. And it's more complicated to work out. I was trying for a SQL solution but being just weekdays that seems difficult.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution. I will need to join to a calendar table on start and end dates and filter for calendar.date >= start and calendar.date<= end. This will give me array of dates associated with each date. Then I can query the result and something like Select Function, count(*) from the created query, and that would give me distinct count of days by function.

This is the gist of it. Obviously, also filtering out weekends on the calendar as well.

Comment: It's a interesting solution. Nice. The downside is that you'll need to generate that calendar table using code, at which point you probably could have done the calculation with code (using a dictionary to collect distinct dates, which is logically similar to using a join to a calendar table to collect those distinct dates).